# How to grab inout from user and modify file using echo or sed

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I am using the below code to get input from user and modify my backup.php file:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter hostname: " hostname
read -p "Enter cPanel username: " user
read -p "Enter password: " pass

echo "\$source_server_ip = \"$hostname\";" >> "backup.php"
echo "\$cpanel_account = \"$user\"; "      >> "backup.php"
echo "\$cpanel_password = \"$pass\"; "     >> "backup.php"
```

This works perfectly; however, I want to insert the user-provided details in backup.php at line numbers 4, 5 and 6, respectively.

backup.php contents:

```
Line no. 1: php
Line no. 2: include xmlapi.php
Line no. 3: (blank)
Line no. 4: $source_server_ip = "   "; 
Line no. 5: $cpanel_account = "   ";
Line no. 6: $cpanel_password = "   "; 
Line no 7 L code continue..
```

I want to keep reset of the code as it is and want to make changes in line no 4,5.6 online.

How can I do this?  Do I need to use sed?

Comment: Do you want to insert them or update current 4th, ... line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to *replace/update* your 4th, 5th and 6th line with some new lines. You can use `sed`'s `s`ubstitution command for this:

```
host_line="\$source_server_ip = \"$hostname\""
user_line="\$cpanel_account = \"$user\""
pass_line="\$cpanel_password = \"$pass\""

sed -i "4s/.*/$host_line/; 5s/.*/$user_line/; 6s/.*/$pass_line/" backup.php

#different notation:
sed -i -e "4s/.*/$host_line/" -e "5s/.*/$user_line/" -e "6s/.*/$pass_line/" backup.php
```

- `4s` determines on which line the substitution command should take place (in this case 4th line)
- `.*` matches the entire line and substitutes it with your user input
- `-i` is in-place editing. It will edit your file instead of sending the result to stdin

**Warning:** using `sed`'s `s` command is really straightforward but it can have some surprising and dangerous results if your variables contain unescaped special characters to `sed`, for example: `&`, `/`, `newline`, ...

---

Or make use of the `sed`'s  `c` command:

```
sed -i "4c \
$host_line
5c \
$user_line
6c \
$pass_line
" backup.php

#different notatiton:
sed -i -e "4c $host_line" -e "5c $user_line" -e "6c $pass_line" backup.php
```

**Warning:** you can manage to break this as well, with unescaped `newline` for example:

```
pass='mypass
2c oops'
```

---

You will either have to escape those special characters to `sed` or use what I consider the safest solution, `awk`:

```
awk -i inplace -v hl="$host_line" -v ul="$user_line" -v pl="$pass_line" '
   NR==4 { $0=hl } 
   NR==5 { $0=ul }
   NR==6 { $0=pl }
   { print }'  backup.php
```

---

Do not forget to use `-r` option with `read` or it will treat backslashes specially.

Also, note that even backslashes in your variables will later get interpreted! You can add extra backslashes with parameter expansion if you want to prevent this:

```
host_line="\$source_server_ip = \"${hostname//\\/\\\\}\""
user_line="\$cpanel_account = \"${user//\\/\\\\}\""
pass_line="\$cpanel_password = \"${pass//\\/\\\\}\""
```

---

**EDIT:** If you just want to *insert* the 3 lines after the 3th line, use this simple `sed`:

```
sed -i "4i $host_line\n$user_line\n$pass_line" backup.php
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add exact line. I have added lines in question now.. I tried and I confirmed that below code works for me
sed -i "4s/.*/$hostname/; 5s/.*/$user/; 6s/.*/$pass/" backup.php

How can I add $source_server_ip = "   "; using this method ?

Comment: @user8863627 I edited my answer, please check some more suggestions.